# How to make a deep copy of a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have the following constructor:

IN THE HPP FILE

```
Card(string name, int mana_cost, CardType type);
```

IN THE CPP FILE

```
Oop::Card::Card(string name, int mana_cost, CardType type)
                : name_(name), mana_cost_(mana_cost), type_(type)
{

}
```

and would like to make a copy constructor of the one above,
 I have tried

```
  Card( const Card &b)
  {
    name_ = new std::string();
    *name_ = *b.name_;
    mana_cost_ = new int();
    type_ = new CardType();
  }
```

but to no avail

How could I make a copy constructor of that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use `new`? Just do `name = b.name;` etc to copy the values - or better, use the member initializer list.

Comment: please include a [mcve] and explain the meaning of "but to no avail". Btw it seems like you just have to remove all `new`. Why did you use `new` for everything? You didnt do anything like that in the constructor

Comment: You may be confusing C++ with other languages. In C++, there is a difference between a pointer to a type (`T*`) and an object of that type (`T`). `new` is used with pointers, values are used with non-pointer objects. The two constructors you show imply a contradiction about what `Card`'s members' types are. In C++, assigning from `A` to `B`  copies the value (implies deep copy). It's only with pointer and pointer wrappers that assignment implies sharing a handle to a common instance.

Answer (score 3):

Your converting constructor does not `new` the class members, so your copy constructor does not need to `new` them, either.  Simply initialize the members in the copy constructor in the same way that the converting constructor does, just using input values taken from the passed `Card` object, eg:

```cpp
Oop::Card::Card(const Card &b)
    : name_(b.name_), mana_cost_(b.mana_cost_), type_(b.type_)
{
}
```

In C++11 and later, you can even *delegate* one constructor to another:

```cpp
Oop::Card::Card(const Card &b)
    : Card(b.name_, b.mana_cost_, b.type_)
{
}
```

Or, the easiest solution is to just `default` the copy constructor and let the compiler handle the copying for you, since your members are using types that support proper copy semantics:

```cpp
class Card {
public:
    Card(string name, int mana_cost, CardType type);
    Card(const Card &) = default; // <--
};
```